# How to store hive query result in json format in a file?

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I want to store the hive query result to a file in JSON format. Through Brickhouse jar I can get the query output in JSON format but am unable to store that in a file or table. The query I'm trying is given below. When the `INSERT OVERWRITE` query runs, it gives an error; how can I solve this error? Is there a way to store query results in JSON format through queries?

**Query:**

```
add jar hdfs:///mydir/brickhouse-0.7.1.jar;

INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/mydir/textfile1'
stored as textfile
SELECT to_json( named_struct( "id",id,
            "name",name))
   FROM link_tbl;
```

**Error:**

```
INFO : Tez session hasn't been created yet. Opening session
INFO : Dag name: INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/mydir/text...pl(Stage-1)
INFO :

INFO : Status: Running (Executing on YARN cluster with App id application_1571318954298_0001)

INFO : Map 1: -/-
ERROR : Status: Failed
ERROR : Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1571318954298_0001_1_00, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1571318954298_0001_1_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:INIT_FAILURE, Fail to create InputInitializerManager, org.apache.tez.dag.api.TezReflectionException: Unable to instantiate class with 1 arguments: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator
at org.apache.tez.common.ReflectionUtils.getNewInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:70)
at org.apache.tez.common.ReflectionUtils.createClazzInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:89)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:151)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:148)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager.createInitializer(RootInputInitializerManager.java:148)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager.runInputInitializers(RootInputInitializerManager.java:121)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.setupInputInitializerManager(VertexImpl.java:4536)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.access$4300(VertexImpl.java:202)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl$InitTransition.handleInitEvent(VertexImpl.java:3352)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl$InitTransition.transition(VertexImpl.java:3301)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl$InitTransition.transition(VertexImpl.java:3282)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$MultipleInternalArc.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:385)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:302)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.access$300(StateMachineFactory.java:46)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$InternalStateMachine.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:448)
at org.apache.tez.state.StateMachineTez.doTransition(StateMachineTez.java:57)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.handle(VertexImpl.java:1862)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.handle(VertexImpl.java:201)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster$VertexEventDispatcher.handle(DAGAppMaster.java:1978)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster$VertexEventDispatcher.handle(DAGAppMaster.java:1964)
at org.apache.tez.common.AsyncDispatcher.dispatch(AsyncDispatcher.java:183)
at org.apache.tez.common.AsyncDispatcher$1.run(AsyncDispatcher.java:114)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.apache.tez.common.ReflectionUtils.getNewInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:68)
... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load plan: hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/tmp/hive/hive/2eaf13cf-1f98-4a2d-8f76-4e9c839f355b/hive_2019-10-17_13-33-05_763_197979924455130156-2/hive/_tez_scratch_dir/d9d1df72-f68c-4c1f-b642-85a46f32a79f/map.xml: org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 19963874, Size: 113
Serialization trace:
_mainHash (org.codehaus.jackson.sym.BytesToNameCanonicalizer)
_rootByteSymbols (org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory)
jsonFactory (brickhouse.udf.json.ToJsonUDF)
genericUDF (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.ExprNodeGenericFuncDesc)
colExprMap (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator)
childOperators (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator)
aliasToWork (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.MapWork)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getBaseWork(Utilities.java:472)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getMapWork(Utilities.java:311)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator.<init>(HiveSplitGenerator.java:101)
... 30 more
Caused by: org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 19963874, Size: 113
Serialization trace:
_mainHash (org.codehaus.jackson.sym.BytesToNameCanonicalizer)
_rootByteSymbols (org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory)
jsonFactory (brickhouse.udf.json.ToJsonUDF)
genericUDF (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.ExprNodeGenericFuncDesc)
colExprMap (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator)
childOperators (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator)
aliasToWork (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.MapWork)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:507)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObjectOrNull(Kryo.java:745)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:113)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:507)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:694)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:106)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:507)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:694)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:106)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:507)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:776)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:139)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:17)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:694)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:106)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:507)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:776)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:112)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:18)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:694)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:106)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:507)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:776)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:139)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:17)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:694)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:106)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:507)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:672)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.deserializeObjectByKryo(Utilities.java:1173)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.deserializePlan(Utilities.java:1062)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.deserializePlan(Utilities.java:1076)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getBaseWork(Utilities.java:432)
... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 19963874, Size: 113
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.MapReferenceResolver.getReadObject(MapReferenceResolver.java:42)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readReferenceOrNull(Kryo.java:820)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObjectOrNull(Kryo.java:743)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:113)
... 65 more
]
ERROR : DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution can be creating table on top of this directory and use the power of JSONSerDe.

Create table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mydirectory_tbl(
  id   string,
  name string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION '/mydir' --this is HDFS/S3 location
;
```

Insert data:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE table mydirectory_tbl
SELECT id,name
   FROM link_tbl;
```

And you cannot specify filename in place of table or directory location. Only directory. If you want one single file, then you can concatenate files later (preferable as more performant) or force single reducer for example by adding `ORDER BY id`.

Comment: I am getting an error while using Json Serder. How can I tackle?   
Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Could not initialize class org.openx.data.jsonserde.objectinspector.JsonObjectInspectorFactory... @leftjoin

Comment: @sidradua Try another serde class: 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'

Comment: Now facing this errorError while compiling statement: FAILED: NoMatchingMethodException No matching method for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFToString with (struct<raw:string>). Possible choices: _FUNC_(bigint) _FUNC_(binary) _FUNC_(boolean) _FUNC_(date) _FUNC_(decimal(38,18)) _FUNC_(double) _FUNC_(float) _FUNC_(int) _FUNC_(smallint) _FUNC_(string) _FUNC_(timestamp) _FUNC_(tinyint) _FUNC_(void) [ERROR_STATUS] @leftjoin